# Remembering email and password

Tags: html, css, ember.js

I have the following problem. When I remember email and password on chrome email fills the latest email field on the page, but not the right one. Here is the image:
[image: img]

This happens on a register page also: [image: img] but it shouldn't be here.

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to prevent users from having inputs automatically filled out based on previously entered values which the browser stored, you can use the `autocomplete="off"` parameter on the input.
Eg. `<input type="password" id="foo" autocomplete="off" ...>`